# Spring Boot Angular js over Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Question is about what are the advantage of using spring-angularjs-java framework over angulatjs-java framework?

As we know For spring-java, JSP can render your page, but after that it runs flat. The advantage is you can rely on java on the front end. Angular, or any javascript framework, will separate the front end from the backend of the application. This gives you a much richer set of options for the front end of the application.
What about using spring - angularjs-java over angularjs-java ?
Thanks

Comment: Seems **primarily opinion-based**: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise*.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application